# In Dart, is there a way to intercept accesses and mutations to programming constructs?

Tags: java, spring, dart, aop, interceptor

For example, the Spring AOP framework for Java offers functionality to provide an interceptor to intercept some processes, for example, when a method is executed - Spring AOP can hijack the executing method, and add extra functionality before or after the method execution.

I want to know if there is something similar to that in Dart. Can you in Dart, for instance, intercept accesses and mutations to a variable? I was not able to find something along those lines in the Dart documentation.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't seen anything along those lines for Dart yet. I can imagine that it could be done for example by a transformer that modifies the code.

Comment: You could implement proxy objects using noSuchMethod().

Comment: I don't think that you can find something even in the Java documentation. Without using of the Spring AOP framework you cannot using these features in Java. Spring AOP does not hijack the executing method. It acts as a post-compiler that executed after the Java compile code to bytecode. It modifies bytecode before it executed. I don't think that you correctly understand how this technique works. In the Dart platform this technique maybe not so helpful becuase it does not uses bytecode. It is a scripting (human readable) langauge and using post-compiler maybe not always possible.

Comment: @mezoni FYI, native Java doesn't have that capability.  However, https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj does, and more.  You can replace javac with ajc if you want, or postprocess compiled .class files.

Comment: @MatthewAdams You wrote `native Java`? Could you explain to me the difference between Java and `native Java`? What else are Java? What happens if I replace `ajc` with `javac`?

Comment: @mezoni I meant plain, vanilla Java.  The JDK supplied by Oracle does not include any AOP features that offer those of AspectJ.

Comment: @MatthewAdams Yeah... vanilla Java, vanilla C#, vanilla Dart. Who is next? Why need to call them as native, vanila? Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do that at *runtime* for now. You could perhaps do something like this once *mirror builders* has landed. From [Reflection in Dart with Mirrors: An Introduction](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/reflection-with-mirrors/)

> We’d like to support more powerful reflective features in the future. These would include *mirror builders*, designed to allow programs to extend and modify themselves, and a mirror-based debugging API as well.

However you can do that at *built-time* either in a pre-processor (like a *build.dart*) or with a [pub transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/). You also use the [analyzer package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) to get the AST if you need it. This can be seen like APT in Java.

Comment: The link gives a 404 at the time of writing. Can you update on this?